# Import opencv in windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, opencv

I have copied the cv2.pyd file in to Python27\Lib\site-packages 
importing CV2 works well but import CV won't works which throws an error.

Error looks like this :

```
 >>> import cv

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
import cv
ImportError: No module named cv
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

I am using python 2.7 on windows pc.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this myself.This was an issue with OpenCV Engine.Downloaded OpenCV engine from https://github.com/thumbor/opencv-engine/releases/tag/1.0.1 and save it as engine.py in \Python27\Lib\site-packages. used cv2.cv instead of cv2.cv as cv.